# Is "not only... but as well..." grammatical?

Tags: grammaticality, punctuation, conjunctions, commas

I was given a text to read by my teacher which contains the following sentence:

> Speaking a foreign language one can not only read the papers, magazines and original books by outstanding writers, but as well watch satellite programmes, use the internet, travel easily to different parts of the world.

Is it correct to use *as well* at the beginning of the phrase after *but*? Should *as well* be set off by commas in this case?

Comment: Please keep your questions to one per post.

Comment: [This answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/21847/3559) might solve the continuous verb question you have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*As well* is an adverb meaning ‘also; in addition’ and its use in your example is grammatical. That, however, is not to say that it is an ideal sentence. Readers might expect *as well*, coming at that stage in the sentence, to be part of *as well as* for which they will look in vain. In terms of style, it might be preferable to break the sentence into two, ending the first at *writers* and beginning the second with *In addition, one can watch . . .*

A further point: *and* is needed between *internet* and *travel*.

Comment: Don’t you think a coordination of *Not only ... but also ... as well* is a more expected form?

Comment: @tchrist Wouldn't *as well* then be redundant?

Comment: @Kris Well, sure: the postfixed *as well* isn’t necessary, since the *also* suffices for that purpose. Think of it as an intensifier.  I just don’t know any good examples of a prefixed *as well* in English; it sounds off to me.